# Where to find DNS A records information in Firebase Hosting for a previously connected custom domain?

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting

When you add a custom domain in Firebae Hosting, **at the end of the process you see two DNS A records** that you should add to your DNS configuration.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain#go-live

[image]

**QUESTION**

But **after you're done with the process** of adding the new custom domain, **where in the Firebase Console can you find the information about those DNS A records** again?

I didn't find it in the Firebase Hosting section nor in my Project Settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that **if the DNS A records have already been detected by Firebase**, they will no longer be accessible from the Firebase Console.

But **if the records haven't been detected by Firebase yet, you be able to see them by clicking on your custom domain** on your console's Firebase Hosting section. It will be marked with **"View Setup"** or something like that (don't remember the exact phrase).

If it's marked as **"pending"**, it's because the records have already been detected and it's waiting for propagation across the DNS network.

It it's marked as **"conected"**, it's because it's already up an running.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen anything within the Firebase console that shows the record information, but the A records are outlined in their per-provider docs lower in the documentation you provided:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain#dns-records-cloudfare